# Can't see any files in my local postgres-data volume

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am using postgres in docker-compose

i have set up my compose yaml like so:

```
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

This works absolutely fine, but i am confused because i can't see any files in the local postgres-data directory. My data is persistent. If i do `docker-compose down` then `docker-compose up` my database has been preserved completely. Where is the data being stored in this intermediary period? is the folder i can see just acting as some sort of symbolic link?

the `postgres-data` is in the same directory as my compose yaml.

I am on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want a bind mount.

E.g.

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./postgres-data
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```